# how to style borders of autocomplete control

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I need to change the borders of autocomplete control.Is it possible to control the border styles through inline styling.can any one help?

Thanks

Comment: share your sample code

Comment: what did you try so far ? try with something like `[style.border]="..."` or `[class.customborder]="..."`

Comment: my code is like following                                                                       <kendo-autocomplete [data]="Customrdata"  style="border-bottom-color:blue;"  [valueField]="'text'"  [filterable]="true"
  (filterChange)="handleFilterCustomer($event)" [value]="InvCustomer" (valueChange)="handleValue($event)"
                                                        >
                                    </kendo-autocomplete>